# Sync Outlook Calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

Since Google Calendar Sync [has been discontinued](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/94020?hl=en), what are some options for syncing Outlook Calendar with Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your Google account through IMAP

> Google now offers similar access via IMAP, CalDAV, and CardDAV, making it possible to build a seamless sync experience using open protocols.

Via Google's [Support Page](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2716936)

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yin0A.png) an example of the IMAP settings.

Answer (score 0):

Or try any third-party tool. I personally use [Sync2](http://sync2.com/) to sync my Outlook calendar and contacts between work desktop and my laptop. 
http://sync2.com/